# Return table value based on a primitive "priority queue"

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have 2 function in Lua, one to look if a key is present inside a provided table and if true then return the value, else return false. This lookup function is called by another function with a "priority queue". It is not a queue per definition but I don't have a better name for it.

```
function inTable(tbl, item)
    for key, value in pairs(tbl) do
        if key == item then 
          return value 
        end
    end
    return false
end

function ReturnString()
local valid = {}

valid[22] = "string1"
valid[13] = "string2"
valid[25] = "string3"
...

  if inTable(valid, "22") then
    return inTable(valid, "22")
  elseif inTable(valid, "13") then
    return inTable(valid, "13")
  elseif inTable(valid, "25") then
    return inTable(valid, "25")
  else
    print("nope not found")
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
print(ReturnString())
```

valid is filled with a lot of different key-value pairs, unordered. My goal is to return the value based on a priority I determine using my nested if-elseif-else construct. If there is a key 22 then return `string1`, else check if there is a key 13 and so on. I know that there are more real implementation of a priority queue like [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Priority_queue) but I prefer something simple. What improvement can I do without implementing a complex priority queue?

Comment: There is a missing `"` in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

welcome to Code Review.

I don't understand the purpose of your `inTable()` function. Lua tables already support immediate lookup of entries in them, just by using square brackets. See [the Lua documentation for tables](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.5.html).

So your code:

> ```
>   if inTable(valid, "22") then
>     return inTable(valid, "22")
>   elseif inTable(valid, "13") then
>     return inTable(valid, "13")
>   elseif inTable(valid, "25") then
>     return inTable(valid, "25)
> ```

is really equivalent to:

```
if valid[22] then
  return valid[22]
elseif valid[13] then
  return valid[13]
elseif valid[25] then
  return valid[25]
```

Can we do better than this? Sure! Lua has the `or` operator which returns the first true value. [(See documentation)](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html)

```
return valid[22] or valid[13] or valid[25]
```

Can we do even better? Definitely. Make up another table with the indexes in order, then iterate over it, returning the first true value.

```
local priority = {22, 13, 25}
local i
for i in priority do
   if valid[i] return valid[i]
end
```

Comment: I got a attempt to call table value error. when using your for loop. `local priority = {22, 13, 25}` and `for i in priority do
    if valid[priority] then
      return valid[priority]
    end
  end`

Comment: nevermind I could fix it. thanks a lot `for i = 1, #priority, 1 do
    if valid[tostring(priority[i])] then
      return valid[tostring(priority[i])]
    end
  end`

Comment: or just put the strings in the priority table anyway; `local priority={"22","13","25"}`

Comment: also see my fix; i put the wrong thing inside the square brackets